# Is bitwise AND, OR, XOR using 8 cpu cycles to get a result?

Tags: bit-manipulation, cpu-usage

If I wanted to bitwise AND or OR or XOR 00001111 and 10101010 and get a result, would that be 8 cpu cycles that compare each of the 8 bits? Or is it actually one cpu cycle that can AND/OR/XOR all these bits?

If it is actually one cpu cycle, does that mean that a 32 bit processor can AND/OR/XOR up to 32 bits (same with 64) in one cpu cycle?

Comment: It depends entirely on the specific CPU, but simple bitwise operations such as this are typically 1 cycle, regardless of operand width, on modern CPUs. See the manual for whichever CPU family you are using.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most modern processors can do _many_ bitwise and/or/xor in a single cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine two integral values that are stored in one data word of the CPU, the logical operation will be done in one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) operate on one or more binary numerals at the level of their individual bits. The operations are most often performed on all bits of the binary number in parallel. The data is usually as large as the processor's native word size. On a 32 bit CPU, a bitwise operation on 32-bit data would take one instruction. On 64-bit data, it would take two instructions.